# Java - How to fill combobox with certain part of txt file

Tags: java, combobox, text-files, jcombobox

I have text file like this:

```
   Jordan|Turner|jotu|12345|Department of Complaints|Belgrade|
   Travis|Bickle|trabic|54321|Driving Department|Novi Sad|
```

And code like this:

```
    package gui;
    public class ReservationWindow extends JFrame {

        private JComboBox cbDispatcher;
        private JLabel lblDispatcherecer;

        public ReservationWindow() {
            setTitle("Reservations");
            ImageIcon ikonica = new ImageIcon
                    (LoginProzor.class.getResource("/ikonice/faketaxi.png"));
            setIconImage(ikonica.getImage());
            setSize(400, 350);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            initGUI();
            initActions();
        }

        private void initActions() {
 //here is everything fine :D
        }

        private void initGUI() {
            MigLayout mig = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[][]", "[]10[][]10[]");
            setLayout(mig);

            cbDispatcher = new JComboBox();
            lblDispatcher = new JLabel("Dispatcher with whom you talked");

            add(lblDispatcher);
            add(cbDispatcher);

        }
    }
```

Now, how to fill ComboBox with certain part of the linse? 
(in this case with 4th part - Department of Complaints and Driving Department)

[image]

Comment: read that file then split string by `|` so that will get array then add respected values in to `jComboBox` by using method `addItem()`

Comment: @Amogh Yes, I understand the logic, and I try to read file with BufferReader etc, and tried on so many ways, but I'm not so sure how to read and split the file on the right way...

Comment: @Amogh 1.8.0_91

Comment: Just do BufferedReader.readLine in a loop. Then for each iteration of the loop, do a String.split on pipe. Take the string at index 4. Collect all those values in a List and you are ready to paint your UI.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `|` in file just for separator then I will suggest remove that and keep each value on each new line for simplicity, java 8 simple way to read file is :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

    list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So now `list` will have all the values from file. Now you have to loop on it and add it to `JComboBox` using `cbDispatcher.addItem(value)`. You can use `stream.filter` to filter (read specific part of file) and give it to `JComboBox`

Answer (score -1):

Parse and store your text file to ArrayList. You can use `split` method of String. Then
use the `toArray()` method of the ArrayList class and pass it into the constructor of the `JComboBox`

See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(java.lang.Object[])) and [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more info.